# Magento DOM error XML

Tags: magento2, error, xml, rest-api, dom

I got some errors when I `setup:upgrade` my file in Magento 2.

this is the error :

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in `/home/cloudpanel/htdocs/swift/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php` on line 451

when I delete my file and setup upgrade again the issue comes again...

anyone can help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Check your third party extension which have space into the starting of xml file :

```
like :


<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

so remove that and then check.